# How to use arc4random in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arc4random

How do I use `arc4random` in JavaScript? I tried to use `var randomNumber = (arc4random() % 83) + 1;` but I got `UncaughtReferenceError: arc4random is not defined.` I am not sure which libs to include to use arc4random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it possible, given all research points to the fact that arc4random is not a js function, but one built in to objective-c, or ios.  I'm beginning to believe you did little research into the matter.  Even the tag wiki entry on SO says as much.

Comment: Agree. Even I did not find any pointers for this function in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

`arc4random()` is not defined in JavaScaript. To generate random numbers in JavaScript you can use `Math.random()`. But I think you can easy emulate `arc4random()` as:

```
function arc4random(){
  return Math.random()*4294967296;
}
```